# Cannot forward to a route method controller different bunde symfony

Tags: symfony, routes

Got the following structure of my bundle:

```
Presentation->Api->Rest->Controller->CoachController->getCoaches
```

And I'm trying from a different bundle to forward to it, but I keep getting the following error:

```
{"error":{"code":500,"message":"Internal Server Error","exception":[{"message":"Class \"Presentation\\Api\\Rest\\Controller:Coach\" does not exist.","class":"InvalidArgumentException",
```

What I've tried is:

```
return $this->forward('Presentation\Api\Rest\Controller:Coach::getCoaches');
```

Any idea why this is not working?

Comment: Check Namespace, class name and method name are correct and try with double backslash. forexample Presentation\\Api\\Rest\\Controller:Coach::getCoaches

Comment: Your format is off just a bit.  https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/forwarding.html

Answer (score 1):

You have probably a typo with your **namespace**, here's a link for the doc: https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/forwarding.html 
Try to update your code: `return $this->forward('Presentation\Api\Rest\Controller\CoachController::getCoaches');`

By the way your `getCoaches` function should looks like this:

```
namespace Presentation\Api\Rest\Controller;
...
class CoachController {
...
    public function getCoaches()
    {
        // ... create and return a Response object
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I found out the solution, I will post it tomorrow (away from laptop until tomorrow)